# Hibernate root item not found on recursive table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When I try to get the root node of a recursive table hibernate doesn't find it.

Table schema:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idbox    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| idparent | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| nom      | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the select of the data table:

```
+----+-------+----------+----------------+
| id | idbox | idparent | nom            |
+----+-------+----------+----------------+
|  1 |     1 |       16 | RDC            |
|  2 |     1 |        1 | salon          |
|  3 |     1 |        1 | cuisine        |
|  4 |     1 |        1 | room invite    |
|  5 |     1 |       16 | etage 1        |
|  6 |     1 |        5 | room parent    |
|  7 |     1 |        5 | room david     |
|  8 |     1 |        5 | room sarah     |
|  9 |     1 |        5 | room rachel    |
| 10 |     1 |        5 | room leon      |
| 11 |     1 |       16 | etage 2        |
| 12 |     1 |       11 | grenier        |
| 13 |     1 |        5 | WC             |
| 14 |     1 |        5 | SDB            |
| 15 |     1 |        6 | SDB-Parent     |
| 16 |     1 |     NULL | root           |
+----+-------+----------+----------------+
```

class Position:

```
public class Position implements Serializable, Comparable<Position>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Lob
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String nom;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Dispositif
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="position")
    private Set<Dispositif> dispositifs;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Box
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idbox", nullable=false)
    private Box box;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Position
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idparent", nullable=false)
    private Position parent;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Position
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",  orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private Set<Position> positions = new HashSet<Position>();
    ...
}
```

So when I add a critieria on my hibernate query (I am searching by idbox=1 and name='root' ) the result is null

The problem occurred only when idparent is set to NULL

2) Does I need to refence the root to himself ?

Any idea why ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please update the question with the code of JPA entity and the Hibernate query you are running? Thanks

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I found the problem but don't know how to resolve it.
The problem is that hibernate make an inner join that reference to himself:
    inner join
        position position4_ 
            on this_.idparent=position4_.id 
    where
        this_.idbox=? 
        and this_.nom=?

Comment: `@JoinColumn(name="idparent", nullable=false)`. Why is this set as non-nullable when you obviously have null values in idparent for root in the database. I think that might have something to do with the generated query when Hibernate thinks that parent id can't be null

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Thanks a lot it's work. I change the schema of my DB (and make this field nulleable) but I forgot the JPA.
Again thank a lot !!

Comment: Glad I could help. Btw I posted the complete solution as an answer. Could you please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that you have defined the `idparent` join column as not nullable even though your database clearly allows `NULL` values for this column.

Based on this Hibernate will think that the parent ID can not contain null values, which will affect the SQL code it generates. In your case it resulted in using `INNER JOIN` as you mentioned in your comment.

To fix it make the join column nullable like so: `@JoinColumn(name="idparent")` (if you look at its source, it is nullable by default, so there is no need to specify it explicitly).